# Def's and break and continue

Tags: python, user-defined-functions, using

I know this won't work but any solutions rather than repeating the bottom section for every option? The issues is `continue` and `break` cannot be put in a `def`

```
while True:
    print (" For + press A, - press B, X press C , / press D\n")
    choice = input ("Enter either A, B, C or D \n").title()
    number1 = int(input ("Now enter the first number(s) of the calculation\n"))
    number2 = int(input ("Now enter the second number(s) of the calculation\n"))
    if choice == "A":
        print (number1,"+",number2,"=",(number1+number2))
        again()
    elif choice == "B":
        print (number1,"-",number2,"=",(number1-number2))
        again()
    elif choice == "C":
        print (number1,"X",number2,"=",(number1*number2))
        again()
    elif choice == "D":
        if number2 == 0:
            print("Error")
        print (number1,"/",number2,"=",(number1/number2))
        again()
    else:
        print ("Error!")
        again()

def again():
    con = input ("Do you want to continue Y or N?".title())
    if con =="Y":
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Also, just put the continue or not question at the end of your while loop instead of putting it in every single if-else branch. There's no need to use a function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

Basically functions can only affect their own flow.

Now, I can't think of an easy way to do what you want, but it's beside the point when you can just move the code from the function to the end of the loop. (I also fixed some other problems with your code.)

```
while True:
    ...
    if choice == "A":
        print(number1, ...)
    elif choice == "B":
        print(number1, ...)
    elif choice == "C":
        print(number1, ...)
    elif choice == "D":
        if number2 == 0:
            print("Error: can't divide by zero")  # Also clarified this
        else:  # Also added this
            print(number1, ...)
    else:
        print("Error: Unrecognized command")  # Also clarified this

    con = input("Do you want to continue Y or N?").title()  # Also fixed typo here
    if con != "Y":  # Also changed this since it will continue by default
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @wjandrea's answer, this control-flow doesn't need `break` or `continue` at all; just change the loop condition from `while True:` to a suitable condition, for example:

```py
con = "Y"
while con == "Y":
    # ...

    con = input("Do you want to continue Y or N?").title()
```

The loop continues when `con == "Y"` and stops otherwise, which is exactly the same behaviour as before.